# New to WX, keep experiencing the same PyNoAppError

Tags: python, attributes, wxpython

I keep getting the same Error and I don't know why. It says that I have to create the wx.App object first, but I feel like I already have.

The error occurs at

```
self.image=wx.Image("cards_gif\\"+fstr+".gif",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
```

Am I not initializing correctly?

```
print 'step 1'
import wx
app=wx.App()
class Card(object):
    print 'step 2'
    d={"h":"hearts","c":"clubs","s":"spades","d":"diamonds"}
    print 'step 3'
    d2={1:"ace",2:"two",3:"three",4:"four",5:"five",6:"six",7:"seven",8:"eight",9:"nine",10:"ten",11:"jack",12:"queen",13:"king"}
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank=rank
        self.suit=suit
        fstr=str(suit)+str(rank)
        self.image=wx.Image("cards_gif\\"+fstr+".gif",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY).ConvertToBitmap()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.d[self.rank]+"of"+self.d2[self.suit]   
    def get_img():
        return self.image
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you create a wxPython app. Are you following a tutorial? If not, Zetcode has a pretty good one: http://zetcode.com/wxpython. You are missing the app.MainLoop(), a wx.Frame, and a panel..some of the basic building blocks of a GUI app.